# What is the need of normalisation in image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I saw this code in the internet

```
imgN = double(img-min(img(:)))/(max(img(:)-min(img(:))));
```

to normalize the image in 0..1 . What's the meaning of it? Also its shows this error

```
Error using  / 
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MATLAB, many functions make assumptions about the range of values in an image. Usually, images are stored either as `uint8` or `double`. In the case of `uint8`, the range is `0...255` (which is all possible values in a `uint8`.). For `double`, MATLAB chose a value range from `0...1`. To use functions like `imshow`, `imwrite` and others correctly, your `double` image has to be scaled correctly, otherwise some pixels are not displayed correctly.

There is a small bug in the code: It is basically a division `a / b`, where `a` is `double(img - min(img(:)))` and `b` is `(max(img(:)) - min(img(:)))`. If your input image is of type `double`, this will work fine. However if it is `uint8` or any other type, the numerator `a` will be converted to `double`, while the denominator `b` stays e.g. `uint8`. You will have a division `double / uint8`. MATLAB tells you in the error message, that it can not mix types in division. An easy solution is to also convert the denominator `b` to `double`:

```
imgN = double(img-min(img(:))) / double(max(img(:)-min(img(:))));
```

Comment: Short and great explanation