# Save image from imshow

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to save the image to a file after doing `imshow(im,[])`; to display it later in GUI. I am trying the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
 New= imshow(uint8(MHI{t}),[]);
 imwrite(New,'TMHI.jpg','jpg')
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try `imwrite(uint8(MHI{t}),'TMHI.jpg','jpg')`. `imshow` doesn't do enything to the data itself. your `New` variable is only a figure handle.

Comment: I need to put `[]` otherwise the image doesn't display correctly. But when I do `imwrite(uint8(MHI{t},[]),'TMHI.jpg','jpg')` I got an error.

Comment: What error message ?

Comment: Normalize your image first! See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724502/what-is-the-need-of-normalisation-in-image/30724782#30724782) on *why* you need to do that. So 1) normalize the image and 2) save the image like Adiel has shown you.

Comment: the `[]` is only for the way that `imshow` display the image on the screen. look here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imshow.html#input_argument_namevalue_displayrange

Comment: @hbaderts Thank you! It works after normalization.

Comment: @Adiel Thank you for your help. Finally it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`imshow`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) function is only used to *show* the image in MATLAB. If you want to save it, you don't need the `imshow` at all. And: the value (`New`) returned by `imshow()` is the handle to the figure. You need that handle if you want to modify how the figure is shown on the screen.

To write the image to the disk, you only need the [`imwrite`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) function, which has the syntax:

> ```
> imwrite(A,filename)
> ```

where `A` is the image array.
If the file name ends with `.jpg`, then MATLAB will create a JPEG image by default, so you don't need to specify that. (But of course, you still can.)

But before saving: you have a problem with the normalization of the image. MATLAB assumes that a `double` image is scaled to `[0,1]` and that a `uint8` image is scaled to `[0,255]`. With `imshow(im,[])` you *override* these defaults and make MATLAB calculate new values. You will experience the same problem when saving. The solution is to normalize the image properly. This can be done using the [`im2uint8`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2uint8.html) function, which scales the input to a maximum value of 255, and converts it to `uint8`. Note that you'll have to remove the minimal value manually, if that is needed:

```
newImage = im2uint8(MHI{t} - min(MHI{t}(:)));
imwrite(newImage,'TMHI.jpg')
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for translating my laziness to an explained answer, and adding the useful information, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

In case you really need to save the contents of the displayed figure in matlab (sometimes also useful when you use imagesc for display as it has some smart logic for properly scaling your value ranges) you might be interested in the [savefig](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savefig.html) and [saveas](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html) which lets you save the contents of a figure. Its also possible to save graphs or figures with subfigures like that.

In that case, you would use something like:

```
F = imshow(uint8(MHI{t}),[]);
saveas('MHI.png');
```

In case you really just need to save the image stored in MHI{t}, hbaderts 's answer is the way to go...

Comment: Thank you, the problem that I faced when saving figure that it has very large white border. So when I display it in GUI it doesn't look that good.

Answer (score 0):

Just use my NormalizeImage function and save the image normaly:

```
img = NormalizeImage(imgDouble);
imwrite(img ,'MyImage.png');
```

My NormalizeImage function:

```
function img8bpp = NormalizeImage(imgDouble)

minImgDouble =  min(imgDouble(:));

factor = (255-0)/(max(imgDouble(:)) - minImgDouble);

%img8bppB = im2uint8(imgDouble-minImgDouble);

img8bpp = uint8((imgDouble-minImgDouble).*factor);

%im2uint8 does not work, duno y
%imgDif = img8bppB - img8bpp;

end
```